# How to store only values of fields into the state in Antd forms

Tags: forms, reactjs, antd

I have crated a basic antd controled form synchronized with my state in Redux store, when fields changes are transmited to my store via the `onFieldsChange` method i get an object with some unwanted propretys in my state.

For the code you can take the one provided in the official documentation

[Store Form Data into Upper Component](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-global-state)

the received object is like one below :

```
{
  "username": {
    "value": "test",
    "name": "username",
    "touched": true,
    "dirty": false,
    "validating": false
  }
}
```

I want to keep my state clean and store only the value, in my state, are these other properties needed or can be recreated like as in the initial load   ?